# Define a recursive sequence for the following formula f(n) = n(n+1)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Define a recursive sequence for the following formula f(n) = n(n+1).

Preferably one only defined by previous $a_n$ terms, i.e., no 'n' terms. If possible that is.

So for example the following produces:
f(n) = n(n+1)

f(n+1) = (n+1)(n+2) 
$\implies$ f(n+1) - f(n) = $n^2 + 3n + 2 - n^2 - n$ = $2n + 2$ $\implies$ f(n+1) = 2n + 2 + f(n)

So that $a_n$ = $a_{n-1} + 2n + 2. $ with $a_1$ = 2.

However this has 'n' in the formula and I would hope to find a formula that only depends only on previous $a_i$ terms. I mean the Fibonacci numbers for example depends only on the previous 2 terms and not on 'n'.

Comment: Notice that is $f(n)=2\sum_{i=1}^nn$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/13688/85660) for the idea and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/13553/85660) for the general formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

$$f(n)=3f(n-1)-3f(n-2)+f(n-3)$$

or, if you prefer,

$$a_n=3a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\qquad\text{with }a_0=0,a_1=2,a_2=6$$

This is based on $(x-1)^3=x^3-3x^2+3x-1$.  If you're familiar with the [Binet formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for Fibonacci numbers, the idea is to use a recursion relation that has $1$ as a repeated root.  To get quadratic growth, it needs to be a cubic, so each value depends on the previous *three* terms.

Comment: Alright, it works, thanks! 
How would one arbitrarily come up with such a formula? 
You say because f(n) is a quadratic we'd require a recursive sequence based on the previous (2+1) = 3 terms?
Why use 1 as a repeated root?

Comment: @AdamStaples, roughly speaking, the Binet formula analysis says that the numbers defined by a recursive formula are given by a linear combination of exponentials of the roots of the associated polynomial, with coefficients that are polynomials (in $n$) each of degree one less than the mulitiplicity of the coefficient's root.  Since you're trying to match an expression that doesn't have any exponential growth, the root needs to be $1$ (since $1^n=1$ doesn't grow), and since $f(n)$ is quadratic, the multiplicity must be $3$.